# Create a nested resource

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

A `User` has_many `emails`. In a nested `user#new` form a new `User` can be created with one `Email`. Submitting this form creates a new `User` but not the associated `EMail`. The `create` function gets the correct data but only creates the `User`.

The log:

```
[info] POST /users
[debug] Processing by MyApp.UserController.create/2
  Parameters: %{"_csrf_token" => "eUYYy4/aGeRCA==", "_utf8" => "✓",
  "user" => %{"emails" => %{"0" => %{"value" => "john@example.com"}}, 
  "first_name" => "John", "last_name" => "Smith"}}
```

**web/controllers/user_controller.ex**

```
[...]
def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
  changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)

  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, user} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "User created successfully.")
      |> redirect(to: user_path(conn, :index))
    {:error, changeset} ->
      render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end
end
[...]
```

Do I have to change something in the controller to fix this or in the model? In Rails it would be `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a call to [`Ecto.Changeset.cast_assoc/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3) in `User.changeset/2`

Something like:

```
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  |> cast_assoc(:emails)
end
```